# Postgre regexp does not work in perl code using dbi

Tags: regex, perl, dbi, psql

i have this simple data in postgres table (data type is character varying):

```
48
2
L
4XL
25.0
25
7.0
```

i have this sql query with regexp match (i want match only numeric like values like 7.0 or 48):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ss.sizecode ~ E'^\\s*[\\d\\.]+\\s*$'
```

this works perfect in command line client psql,
but does not work in perl code:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    q(SELECT * FROM table WHERE ss.sizecode ~ E'^\\s*[\\d\\.]+\\s*$')
 );
$sth->execute
while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    # no data i want
}
```

Comment: Please show the exact Perl code you're using, the output you're getting, the reason you think it's not working, and any errors you're getting.

Comment: Remove the extra backslashes, perhaps? And be watchful of variable interpolation in `$'`. Use `q()` to quote the string, not double quote `"`.

Comment: Any reason for using `E''` string literal? Just use the normal string literal, and you won't have to worry about escaping ``\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literal

```
q(SELECT * FROM table WHERE ss.sizecode ~ E'^\\s*[\\d\\.]+\\s*$')
```

produces the string

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ss.sizecode ~ E'^\s*[\d\.]+\s*$'
```

To get

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ss.sizecode ~ E'^\\s*[\\d\\.]+\\s*$'
```

you need

```
q(SELECT * FROM table WHERE ss.sizecode ~ E'^\\\\s*[\\\\d\\\\.]+\\\\s*$')
```